# How to use custom credentials in database authentication in Play Framework?

Tags: authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need that in a Intranet application that is made with Play Framework 2, the credentials that the users have for authentication can also be used to authenticate to the database and that every statement sent to it also uses this credentials.

In other words, to each user of the application corresponds a database user and password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This means you won't be able to use the connection pool, and instead you will create a connection-per-request sort of, right? No built in support in play for this, but probably not very hard to do yourself.

The exact solution depends on how you will access your database (Slick, ANORM, something else?) but basically you will have to create some abstraction that takes auth and creates a database session that your database interacting code will use.